# Series of sine functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to ask whether such property is known.

Let us consider the equations:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n))=0,\\  
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x}\sin(y\ln(n)+\varphi)=0,\\  
$$
$$
x\in (0,1), y\in \mathbb{R}, \varphi\neq k\pi, k\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Then their solutions $(x,y)$ are equal to $(\Re(\varrho_{k}),\Im(\varrho_{k}))$ where
$\varrho_{k}$ are non trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is explained here: [On some property of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ in the complex plane](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380577/on-some-property-of-the-zeros-of-zetas-in-the-complex-plane/380596#380596)

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x-i(y+\frac{\varphi}{\ln(n)})}= \exp(-i\varphi)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-x-iy} = 0.
$$